# Compile error about std::future

Tags: c++, c++11, future

Code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

int foo(int n) {
    n = n*1000;
    sleep(1);
    return n;
}

int main(void) {
    std::packaged_task<int (int)> task(std::bind(foo, 3));
    std::future<int> f(task.get_future());

    std::thread trd(std::move(task));
    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gcc report:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/future:38:0,
                 from a.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<std::packaged_task<int(int)>()>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:137:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = std::packaged_task<int(int)>; _Args = {}]’
a.cpp:16:33:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::packaged_task<int(int)>()>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^   
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/functional:1727:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<std::packaged_task<int(int)>()>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^   
make: *** [a] Error 1
```

My gcc version is *4.8.2* on fedora 20

Comment: The `packaged_task` type takes an `int` parameter, but the bound `foo` takes no parameters.

Comment: @Mankarse Could you post an answer? Thanks. If good I'll use it.

Comment: @Mankarse Oh, I catch it. Fix line 13 to `std::packaged_task<int (int)> task(foo);` and line 16 to `std::thread trd(std::bind(std::move(task), 3));` Thank you! +1 for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `foo` is declared as:

```
int foo(int);
```

It has the function type `int(int)` (taking a parameter `int` and returning `int`).

However, the resulting *callable* returned by `std::bind` when you bind `3` to the first parameter has a different function type: `int()`, e.g.:

```
auto func = std::bind(foo, 3) // Bind 3 to the first parameter.
func();                       // Calling func requires no parameter.
```

### Solution

The template parameter specified when declaring the `std::packaged_task` should be specified as `int()`, e.g.:

```
std::packaged_task<int()> task{std::bind(foo, 3)};
```

**Alternatively** don't bind the parameter to `3` when constructing the `std::packaged_task`, instead supply it directly when creating the `std::thread` object:

```
std::packaged_task<int(int)> task{foo}; // Don't bind 3
auto f = task.get_future();

std::thread trd{std::move(task), 3};    // Supply 3 here instead.
std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
```

### Furthermore

- Make sure to call `trd.join()` before returning from function `main`.
- When using `std::thread` also use the sleep function from the *Standard Library* instead of the non-portable `sleep`, e.g.:

  ```
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  ```
- Also when using `std::move` you should include the header `<utility>` in case the other headers don't include it.